# Cannot access the internet via WLAN bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I am having some massive problems with my network setup and was hoping that you can help me.

One one side, I have my cable modem + router (AVM FRITZ!Box 6360) that is working as router and wireless access point. The router's address is 192.168.178.1. My TV is connected via LAN and I have two Android mobile devices connected via WLAN. All communicate without issues with the Internet and between each other.

On the other side, I have a TP-LINK TL-WDR3600 router running DD-WRT. The WAN port is disabled and I have my PC, NAS and wireless loudspeaker connected to three of the four LAN ports. The router's IP address is 192.168.178.2, so it's in the same subnet as the FRITZ!Box. The DHCP server is disabled and the WLAN is operating in client bridge mode. All three connected devices obtain a dynamic IP from the FRITZ!Box' DHCP server. The default gateway and primary DNS assigned is 192.168.178.1, the IP of the FRITZ!Box. My PC for example can connect fine to the FRITZ!Box or any other device connected to either the TP-LINK or the FRITZ!Box and vice versa, so "internal" communication makes no trouble in any direction.

Initially, the devices connected to the TP-LINK can also access the Internet at full speed, but after a few minutes, this is no longer possible. To rule out DNS issues, I tried calling the IP addresses of some sites directly and it still doesn't work. If I issue a ping on 8.8.8.8 (a Google server) for example, I either get a timeout or the error that the destination network is unreachable. For some reason, the timeout is counted as loss, the destination network unreachable errors not. If I do an ipconfig /release followed by ipconfig /renew, I can access the Internet again for some minutes.

Any idea what might be going on here?

(Since it might be confusing, when the connection to the Internet "drops" for the TP-LINK clients, they can still access any internal network device, no matter if it's connected to the TP-LINK or the FRITZ!Box, so it's not the WLAN connection that drops.)

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be doing it correctly.

Try isolating the problems. Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from your TP-LINK DD-WRT router's shell?

Can you tracert 8.8.8.8 from your laptop when your internet connection appears to be gone?

Would it work if you use static IP on your laptop?

Comment: SSHed to the router and it cannot ping 8.8.8.8 either. Tracerouting from my PC gives first hop the TP-LINK router, second hop already target host unreachable.

Comment: OK, there are two screens where you can enter IPs in DD-WRT. The first one is the screen where you enter the IP of the router (192.168.178.2), subnet mask (255.255.255.0), gateway (192.168.178.1) and DNS (either 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.178.1, DD-WRT article says both work), and there is the second screen under Wireless where there is a Default GW Mode. I changed that from Auto (DHCP) to Manual and entered 192.168.178.1 as well, and now it seems to work better. The connection did drop two times in 20 minutes now, but it was restored automatically (and twice in 20 min is much better than before).